# What is the probabilty of missile hit?

Tags: probability

If a Submarine fires two torpedos, with a probability of hit of 25%. 
What is the probability that (a) one torpedo strikes the target or (b) both strikes the ?

I used binomial distribution and got 3/8 for a, and my solutions manual says 1/8? 
Am I wrong?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: "I used binomial distribution" and came up with what?

Comment: My bad, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: I get 3/8 for exactly one torpedo strikes the target, and 1/16 for both do.

Comment: okey then I am right! Has to be an error in the manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you split it into independent events, then the probabilities are:

```
                  | Missile #1 Hits  | Missile #1 Misses
------------------|------------------|------------------
Missile #2 Hits   | 0.25*0.25 = 1/16 | 0.25*0.75 = 3/16
------------------|------------------|------------------
Missile #2 Misses | 0.75*0.25 = 3/16 | 0.75*0.75 = 9/16
```

---

a) The probability that exactly $1$ missile hits the target is $\frac{6}{16}$

b) The probability that exactly $2$ missiles hit the target is $\frac{1}{16}$